# INSTALL_FAILED_CONFLICTING_PROVIDER even when defining provider in Manifest and ApplicationId in GradleFile

Tags: android, android-manifest, react-native, manifest

I set `provider` in manifest, `applicationId` in build.gradle but still getting the `INSTALL_FAILED_CONFLICTING_PROVIDER` error from another app I had installed using the same library (provider), uninstalling the app works but it is not the solution I need.

Tried setting the `applicationId` in build.gradle, setting the `provider` name, `authorities` and `exported` to false in manifest.

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<application...
    <provider
        android:name="com.sample.unique"
        android:authorities="com.sample.app"
        android:exported="false" />
```

android/app/build.gradle

```
defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.another.data.provider"
        minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
```

The app should install? Or am I missing something? this is the library (provider) I'm having conflicts with: `mauron85/react-native-background-geolocation`

This is the output log:

```
com.android.builder.testing.api.DeviceException:
com.android.ddmlib.InstallException: 
INSTALL_FAILED_CONFLICTING_PROVIDER: Package couldn't be installed in 
/data/app/com.a.data.provider-v2vDNK1p47vixkJzr9jU_Q==: Can't 
install because provider name 
com.marianhello.app.mauron85.bgloc.provider (in package 
com.a.data.provider) is already used by 
com.another.data.provider
```

Comment: It sounds like that library is registering a provider in both apps. Provider names must be unique, but maybe the library does not make its provider unique.

Answer (score -1):

The library is using the same package name for all apps. You can define to use unique package name in `app/build.gradle`.

Example:

```
...
defaultConfig {
  ...
  resValue "string", "mauron85_bgloc_content_authority", "com.marianhello.app.mauron85.bgloc.provider.devbuild"
}
```

Reference:
https://github.com/mauron85/react-native-background-geolocation/issues/344